# How to setup x86 paging? Getting triple fault error

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, bochs

I have a toy kernel that I'm working with running under x86 on bochs. When I enable paging, bochs resets with a triple fault error. It seems that it is every and any memory access which triggers the error. So, I'm assuming that I have an error with setting up paging, and the issue is not with my interrupt handler. Here is the code.

**paging.c**

```
#include "paging.h"
#include "lib.h"
#include "screen.h"
#include "descriptor_tables.h"

typedef struct page_dir_entry_s{
    bool present:1;
    bool writeable:1;
    bool user_access:1;
    bool write_through:1;
    bool cache_disabled:1;
    bool accessed:1;
    bool unused0:1;
    bool use_mb:1;//makes pages 4MB not 4KB
    bool unused1:4;
    u32 frame:20;
} page_dir_entry_t;

typedef struct page_table_entry_s{
    bool present:1;
    bool writeable:1;
    bool user_access:1;
    bool write_through:1;
    bool cache_disabled:1;
    bool accessed:1;
    bool dirty:1;
    bool unused0:1;
    bool global:1;
    bool unused1:3;
    u32 phys_page_addr:20;
} page_table_entry_t;

extern u32 end;//as declared in the linker script

static u32 next_addr=0;
static page_dir_entry_t* page_dir=NULL;
static page_table_entry_t* page_table=NULL;

extern void enable_paging(u32);

void InitPaging(){
    next_addr=end;
    while((next_addr%4096)!=0)
        ++next_addr;
    page_dir=(void*)next_addr;
    next_addr+=4*1024;
    memset(page_dir,0,4*1024);
    page_table=(void*)next_addr;
    next_addr+=4;
    u32 addr=0;
    u32 i=0;
    *(((u32*)page_table)+i)=0;//zero it out
    while(addr<next_addr){
        page_table[i].present=true;
        page_table[i].writeable=true;
        page_table[i].phys_page_addr=addr;
        ++i;
        *(((u32*)page_table)+i)=0;//zero it out
        addr+=(1024*4);//4KB
        next_addr+=4;
    }

    page_dir[0].writeable=true;
    page_dir[0].present=true;
    page_dir[0].frame=(u32)page_table;

    enable_paging((u32)page_dir);
}
```

**paging_asm.s**

```
[global enable_paging]
enable_paging:
    mov eax,[esp+4]
    mov cr3,eax
    mov eax,cr0
    or eax,0x80000000
    mov cr0,eax
    ret
```

Comment: Did you put your stack after the kernel? If so, any stack access would cause this (triple fault since you can't handle an interrupt without a stack). If your bochs has the debugger enabled, use `show dbg-all` to get more information on the cause. Also, to round `next_addr` up without a loop: `next_addr = (next_addr + 0xFFF) & 0xFFFFF000`

Comment: When I run it, next_addr=0x250A8000 and esp=0x7FE2C, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Minimal working paging example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/24988411adf10cf9f6afd1566e35472eb8ae771a/paging.S

Answer (score 1):

The "frame" and "phys_page_addr" fields are bits 32 through 12 (in this paging mode) of the physical address.

Paging doesn't do anything with the offset (0 - 4K).

At the least, you need:

```
page_table[i].phys_page_addr=addr >> 12;
```

and

```
page_dir[0].frame=((u32)page_table) >> 12;
```

Since both 'addr' and 'page_table' are aligned to 4096, this just removes the extra zeros.